# Devpartner reports GROOVEEX.DLL Leak exiting program

Tags: devpartner

I'm using DevPartner 10.6.424.1 on x64 side, I see the huge leak in Grooveex.dll, i don't directly use this dll, i'm also seeing lots of false positive leaks. Anyone have experienced?, it is because devpartner is not good for x64 side?, any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I have DevPartner 11.0.0 and it's reporting 8 errors in TortiseGit, 1 in dropbox, 1 in GROOVEEX.DLL (Microsoft), and 1 in mdnsNSP.dll (Apple).  It also reports 75 leaks in mdnsNSP.dll.  My code uses none of these dlls.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm one of the developers on BoundsChecker.  Could you bottle up a small example of this problem?  Then I might be able to test it under my microscope.  Other than that, I could only suggest you try our latest build . . . though that would require you to upgrade your license to 11.0.

The product has not been static: we have resolved quite a few issues since build 10.6.424.1, though I cannot guarantee we will have resolved your particular issue.

Comment: Can you explain why BoundsChecker is reporting on Dlls that my program isn't using?  It's very confusing.

Comment: BoundsChecker will never report a DLL that wasn't loaded into the process directly or indirectly.  We intercept the loading and initialization of every DLL loaded into the process space.  Whether you intended to load a particular DLL is immaterial.  Many DLLs are loaded as a side effect of extensions to (say) the File Open dialog.  Case in point: DropBox extends your application with extra code, whether you like it or not.

Comment: Actually, the OpenFile dialog explaination is a good one, that explains all the dlls I observed I think.  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Your question made me remember a comment from one of our inner circle (close customers / impromptu beta testers) about a year ago, where he said he didn't have DropBox installed on his test system because its presence skewed his testing results. There are many such extensions out there: FileZilla comes to mind, for instance.

Comment: FWIW, a simple test of the generic "MFC Application" sample that comes with Visual Studio 2012 resulted in memory leaks from both GROOVEEX.dll and DropboxExt64.22.dll on my system...